# MySQL and Do While loop timing out

Tags: php, mysql, do-while

This is timing out without echo-ing anything as well as not inserting into database. Can't see why. Any ideas?

**Note** It's to simply generate a number of code numbers, I'm aware that it's simple and insecure, it's being done on localhost only and the connection values are sound.

```
function populate_codes(){
  $con = mysql_connect(dbhost,dbuser,dbpass);
  mysql_select_db(dbname);
  $i = 0;
  do{
    $code = rand(10000000,99999999);
    $check = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.dbcodetable.' WHERE code = $code',$con);
    if(!$check){
        $insertcode = mysql_query('INSERT INTO '.dbcodetable.' (code,status) VALUES ($code,1)',$con);
        if($insertcode){
            echo $i.' - '.$code.'<br />';
            $i++;
        }
     }
  }
  while($i <= 1999);
  echo "------------------------<br /><strong>Complete</strong>";
}
```

Comment: None. Not a single error. It's just not doing anything

Comment: did you try it with less iteration?

Comment: I tried at 200, still nothing. Not timing out though, just white screen (no echos)

Comment: @notulysses - Assumed necessary - http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

Comment: Maybe `$i` will never be 2000 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You:

1. set `$i` to 0
2. generate a random number
3. perform an SQL query
4. **check if the query execution returned `false`**
5. only if it did, and some more conditions apply, are you finally incrementing `$i`
6. you repeat this until `$i` is incremented beyond 1999

The problem is that your 4th step **always succeeds**. The query always executes successfully, `mysql_query` always returns a **result set**. You have to inspect the result set to see what's in it, not just test it against `== false`. So, `$i` never increments.

You also want to increment `$i` outside all those ifs, or have a general protection against infinite loops.

Comment: Thanks @deceze, that did it! changed the "if" to $num = mysql_num_rows($check);if($num < 1){ ....